# Merge the following tags: "contributed-themes," "theme," and "themes"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There are three tags that are used for themes, and that have a similar purpose: [contributed-themes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contributed-themes), [theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme), and [themes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes).

Normally the plural form is used for such tags (but not for [api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api), for example); contributed themes are still themes, and I don't see any reason to make such distinction.

Those tags should be merged with [themes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes), and made synonyms of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged [theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme) into [themes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes) and set up a synonym.